# How to get stored procedure internal Declare Variable value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, parameters, output

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSP 
    (@PARAM INT,
     @PARAM2 NVARCHAR(34),
     @OUTPARAM3 NVARCHAR(34) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RParam INT
    DECLARE @ErrParam2 NVARCHAR(34)

    IF(@PARAM = 1 AND @PARAM2 = 'abc' )
    BEGIN
        SET @OUTPARAM3 = 'EQUAL'
        SET @RPARAM = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ERRPARAM2 = 'SOME ERROR..MSG'
        SET @RPARAM = -1
    END

    RETURN @RPARAM
END
```

And I am trying to get the value of the internally declare variable value.

```
DECLARE @RParam INT
DECLARE @ErrParam2 NVARCHAR(34)
```

`@RParam` is returned but how can I return `@ErrParam2` value?

```
Declare @RP int
Declare @ErrMsg Nvarchar(40)

Exec @RP = MYSP 1,'abc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the output parameter both when the stored procedure is defined and when it is called:

```
Declare @RP int;
Declare @ErrMsg Nvarchar(40);

Exec @RP = MYSP 1, 'abc' , @ErrMsg output;
```

Comment: Yes by using OUTPUT param we can get the value.